# Extracting Mathematical text from pdf using itext

Tags: java, pdf, latex, itext

I have a pdf textbook which has math equations like this: [image: Sample PDF]

However, if i attempt a simple text extraction i get something along the lines of:
V(r) = - 3 - - 
2R R2
This is not an image, it is text but I don't know how to preserve the way it looks and get the actual characters into a text file.

Comment: This is an old link, but I'm guessing it's still true: "iText is not TeX.
In TeX you have operators to draw such formulas.
In iText you have to draw everything yourself.": http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Display-mathematical-formula-using-iText-td2151852.html.  SUGGESTION: examine the .pdf contents with [iText RUPS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrups/)

Comment: I'm not familiar with postscript, is it a format itext can export pdf data in?

Comment: ["Postscript"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) is basically the "P" in .pdf ([Portable Document Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format)).

Comment: Aw, don't say that. There's a world of difference between PostScript and PDF; they really shouldn't be thrown on the same heap.

Comment: And the link posted here actually points to the opposite problem (formula -> PDF rather than PDF -> formula) but it still points to the essential truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are running into is a frequently encountered one. PDF essentially doesn't care about structure. It has no notion of a column, paragraph, a line of text or even a word, let alone a mathematical formula with lots of special formatting.

PDF - essentially - is only interested in placing things on a page at a specific location. And that's exactly what it does with your formulas as well, it will use the characters and graphics you need for your formulas and put them somewhere on the page. Without any additional knowledge that you could use afterwards to figure out that these characters and graphics even belong to a formula; let alone reconstruct it while doing text extraction.

Two additional points:

1) If you share an example of such a PDF document, we could have a look if there is some useful information in it that could be used to extract this formula in a more competent way; but the chance is close to zero.

2) You would also have to define what a "useful way" from your point of view is. Formulas don't translate well to plain text files, so you probably need something like MathML to store them in.

Comment: I see. Is there a way I could somehow print out this section/equation in the pdf as an image? Is there a library with functionality that would enable me to somehow feed it coordinates where text usually is on a page for a pdf and return an image? What are my alternatives?

Comment: Your best bet is download iText RUPS (or a similar tool) and see how the elements in question are coded... PS: Yes, Postscript and PDF are "different". For starters, the latter is a document format, and the former is a language. But they are very closely inter-related. They're both from the same vendor. IMO, they very much *ARE* "from the same heap". Here's a link that explains further: http://adobe.com/print/features/psvspdf

Comment: You can definitely find libraries that would convert part of a PDF document into an image. The challenge would be to find which parts of which page are a formula that you would like to extract as an image as opposed to text which you would like to extract as text. If you have knowledge about the format (if it's fixed layout in some sense) this could be done. If you have arbitrary PDF files without fixed layout, this is going to be close to impossible (or at least really hard).

Comment: I know the differences between PostScript and PDF; I've worked on both a PostScript editor (Tailor) and a PDF editor (PitStop) actually. The reason I don't want to throw them all on the same heap is because one is a programming language, has a sequential format, and is device dependent (amongst other things) while the other has been designed from scratch *not* to be all of those things.